# Field Dependencies with Repeat Tag

Tags: apex, picklist, dependent-picklist

I am new to the visualforce development. Right now i am going through developer guide.

I am little confused about apex: repeat tag

Dependent Picklist Considerations

• You can mix controlling and dependent fields across various field types, such as picklists, multi-picklists, radio buttons, and checkboxes.

> • There’s a limit of 10 dependent picklist pairs per page. This is
>   totalled across all objects. Thus, you could have five dependent
>   picklists on Account, and five on Contact, but no more. However, you
>   can repeat the same pair of dependent picklists, such as in an
>   iterative tag like , without counting more than once
>   against your limit.

So, it means shall we create a custom dependency picklist through the apex with out counting the limits of the dependent picklist?

Will someone helps me to understand specific use case of repeat tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limit applies only to automatically generated dependency support. You can write custom dependencies in JavaScript or Apex without limits (assuming no governor limits are violated). The point of using built-in field dependencies is that you don't have to write any extra code. One typical use of apex:repeat is a dynamically created input form based on a list of fields from a custom setting or field set. The note that you found simply states that automatic field dependencies are limited to 10 per page.